# Check the form to be new or not

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

is there a way to check inside the form class in symfony 1.3 whether it is new or not ? 
Tried the obvious way to check `$this->isNew()` but it gives an error.
Thanks

Comment: `$this->isNew()` should work, but only if the form is an instance of `sfFormObject`. I think that is not your case then,... why do you need this feature on a not object form? Maybe you could use an option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Doctrine then you could get the object and see if that is new :

```
$form->getObject()->isNew();
```

Comment: thank you @ManseUK , you gave me a hint how to implement that in my case.